# NameError in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, syntax-error

When I'm trying this with the following configuration :

- VirtualEnv with python3.4.3
- Running on an online IDE

When I'm trying this :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/pages1.html")

if html is None:
        print("url not found")
else:
    except HTTPError as e:
        print("test")
    else:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
        print(bsObj)
```

I got the following error :

```
~/workspace/scrapingEnv $ python test2.py
  File "test2.py", line 7
    if html is None:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You have that `try`/`except` and `if`/`else` nested oddly...

Comment: Indentation is significant in Python, if that's an accurate representation of the formatting of your file it's not valid Python.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hints, I found a way to get around my problem :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:
    html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscrapng.com/pages/pages1.html")
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    print(bsObj)

except HTTPError as e:
    print("test")
except URLError as j:
    print ("No URL")
else:
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    print(bsObj)
```